# JWT Token generated always results in 401 when submitted to Apple servers

Tags: jwt, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I am using the following code in PHP to generate a JWT token to use with the App Store Server API:

```
$keyId = 'provided by apple';
    $priv_key = <<<EOD
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    provided by apple
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    EOD;

    $pem_private_key = file_get_contents('AuthKey.pem');

    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem_private_key);
    $public_key_pem = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key)['key'];
    $public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($public_key_pem);
   
    $headers = [
        "kid"=> $keyId,
        "typ" => 'JWT'
    ];
    $payload = [
        "iss" => "provided by apple",
        "iat"  => time(),
        "exp"  => time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7),
        "aud" => "appstoreconnect-v1",
        "bid" => "com.bundle.my"
    ];
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $priv_key, 'ES256', $keyId, $headers);
```

This results in a JWT token. However when I try to use it with the Apple Store API, I always get 401 Unauthorized; Unauthenticated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the expiration time as Apple only allows an expiration of max 20 mins.

Changed to time() + 1200.